# using apply to compute max and min of list of vectors

Tags: r

Using below code I'm attempting to return max and min of vector of vectors :

```
v <- 1:5
v2 = list(v , v)
o <- lapply(v2 , function(x) c(max = max(v2) , min = min(v2)))
o
```

v2 contains two vectors of elements 1-5.

The max and min of each function is applied 10 times (the combined size of the inner vectors of v2)

```
> o
[[1]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[2]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[3]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[4]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[5]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[6]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[7]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[8]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[9]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[10]]
max min 
  5   1
```

Can apply function be modified so that just list that contains the max and min values are returned once instead of multiple times ?

Comment: Did you meant `o <- lapply(v2 , function(x) c(max = max(x) , min = min(x)))`

Comment: Eventually you want `sapply(v2 , function(x) c(M = max(x) , m = min(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually speaking, [`lapply`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/) treats its first argument as a sequence of stuffs over which it will iterates to apply the function (why not defined on purpose, actually like you do).

This means that `x` is actually representative of the objecs that are successively passed to the defined function. Thus

```
> lapply(v2 , function(x) c(max = max(x) , min = min(x)))
[[1]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[2]]
max min 
  5   1
```

does the job.

---

To make things clearer, let's do that in a more decomposed fashion. Let's first define a function and then use it as a second argument of `lapply`.

```
> myfn <- function(x) c(max = max(x) , min = min(x))
```

We stored our [callable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callable_object) in a variable named `myfn`. Let's use it

```
> myfn(1:5)
max min 
  5   1
```

Or let's do it by using `lapply` that will do like (just) above over each elements of a given object, say, `v3`:

```
> v3 = list(1:5 , 15:20)
> lapply(v3 , myfn)
[[1]]
max min 
  5   1 

[[2]]
max min 
 20  15
```